# How to make a dynamic form in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to ask something as a Codeigniter newbie.

I want make a dynamic form in CI, if I want increase a form, I can click " Increase" then the form will increase at the bottomw, and if click "Increase" too many times I can click "Delete" then the form will decrease..

I made it with the dynamic form, but my problem arises when I want to save it to the SQL database.

My code is like this :

tambah_material.php

```
    <div id="isi">
<h1>Material Order</h1><br />
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/adminweb/calon"><div class="submitButton">List Material Order</div></a>
<br><br><br><br><table width="100%">
<form method="post" id="myfrm" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/adminweb/simpanmaterial">
<tr><td width="200">Project Name</td><td width="10" align="center">:</td><td><input type="text" class="input" name="nama_lengkap" size="100" /></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200">Project Status</td><td width="10" align="center">:</td><td>
<select name="nama" class="input">
<option value="Under Project Implementation" selected="selected">Under Project Implementation</option><option value="Under Warranty">Under Warranty</option>
<option value="Project Warranty">Project Warranty</option><option value="Out of Warranty">Out of Warranty</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200">Site/Hop Name</td><td width="10" align="center">:</td><td><input type="text" class="input" name="nim" size="50" /></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200">Material Description</td><td width="10" align="center">:</td><td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var nomor = 0;
            var status="";
            $(".tambah").click(function(){
            nomor ++;
                $('#konten').append(
                             '<tr class="baris">'
                         + '<input name="nomor[]" value="'+ nomor +'" type="hidden"></td>'
                         + '<td><input name="tempat_'+ nomor +'" type="text" size="40"></td>'
                         + '<td><input name="sn_'+ nomor +'" type="text" size="60"></td>'
                         + '<td><input type="button" id="hapus" value="Hapus"></td></tr>'
                    );
                });

                $("#hapus").live('click', function () {
                    $(this).parents(".baris").remove();
                });

                $("#myfrm").validate({
                debug: false,
                rules: {
                },
                messages: {
                },

            });
        });

    function tampilTabel()
    {
        if(status=="")
        {
            $('#tabel').slideDown();
            status="1";
        }
        else
        {
            $('#tabel').slideUp();
            status="";
        }
    }
    </script>
    <a class="tambah" style="cursor:pointer; padding:6px; border:1px solid #000; background-color:#FF9900; color:#000000;">Tambah Form</a>
    <br><br>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td>Nama Material : 
    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
    Serial Number :</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="konten"><td></td><td>   

<tr><td width="150">Reason/Suspect Problem</td><td width="10">:</td><td>
<select name="jk" class="input">
<option value="Interference" selected="selected">Interference</option><option value="Lightning Strike">Lightning Strike</option>
<option value="Leakage Shelter">Leakage Shelter</option><option value="Replace Broken One">Replace Broken One</option>
<option value="Borrow">Borrow</option><option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td width="200">Returned to RWH</td><td width="10" align="center">:</td><td><input type="text" class="input" name="alamat" size="70"/></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200">Quantity</td><td width="10" align="center">:</td><td><input type="text" class="input" name="jml" size="70"/></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200">Status</td><td width="10" align="center">:</td><td>
<select name="status" class="input">
<option value="yes" selected="selected">Yes</option><option value="no">No</option></select>
</select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td width="200"></td><td width="10" align="center"></td><td><input type="submit" value="Simpan Data" class="input" /> <input type="reset" value="Hapus" class="input" /></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
```

adminweb.php (controller)

```
function simpanmaterial() 
{
    $data=array();
    $data2=array();
    $session=isset($_SESSION['username_belajar']) ? $_SESSION['username_belajar']:'';
    if($session!=""){
    $pecah=explode("|",$session);
    $data["username"]=$pecah[0];
    $data["nama"]=$pecah[1];
    $data["status"]=$pecah[2];
    $data['scriptmce'] = $this->scripttiny_mce();
        if($data["status"]=="admin"){
            $tgl = " %Y-%m-%d";
            $time = time();
            $in["nama"]=$this->input->post('nama');
            $in["nim"]=$this->input->post('nim');
            $in["nama_lengkap"]=$this->input->post('nama_lengkap');
            $in["alamat"]=$this->input->post('alamat');
            $in["jk"]=$this->input->post('jk');
            $in["jml"]=$this->input->post('jml');
            $in["status"]=$this->input->post('status');
            $in["tempat_1"]=$this->input->post('tempat_1');
            $in["tempat_2"]=$this->input->post('tempat_2');
            $in["tempat_3"]=$this->input->post('tempat_3');
            $in["tempat_4"]=$this->input->post('tempat_4');
            $in["sn_1"]=$this->input->post('sn_1');
            $in["sn_2"]=$this->input->post('sn_2');
            $in["sn_3"]=$this->input->post('sn_3');
            $in["sn_4"]=$this->input->post('sn_4');
            $in["tanggal"] = mdate($tgl,$time);
            $in["penulis"] = $data["username"];
            if($in["nama_lengkap"]=="" || $in["nim"]=="" || $in["alamat"]=="")
            {
                echo "Data masih kosong..!!!";
            }
            else{
            $this->Admin_model->Simpan_Artikel("tbl_mahasiswa",$in);
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=".base_url()."index.php/adminweb/insbaru'>";
            }
        }
        else{
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        alert("Anda tidak berhak masuk ke Control Panel Admin...!!!");
        </script>
        <?php
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=".base_url()."index.php/'>";
        }
    }
    else{
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    alert("Anda belum Log In...!!!\nAnda harus Log In untuk mengakses halaman ini...!!!");
    </script>
    <?php
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=".base_url()."index.php/'>";
        }
}
```

thanks for your help

Best Regards,
Karisma

Comment: WAIT! What you mean is discontinued? Where did you see that?

Comment: oh i think discountinued,hehehe
sorry, i listened wrong information..
maybe you can help me @Mr.Web?

Comment: Gosh! You scared me! I still use it and version 3 is coming out soon (now in beta)... Ok you are forgiven this time.. :D

Comment: hehe, i'm sorry..
coz my friend said like that 3 months ago,hehehe
sorry...

Comment: hei @Mr.Web , it's very helpfull if your forgiven together with your answer..wkwkwk..how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making your code Dynamic you can grab a existing MY_MODEL from [github](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiJhN7tspvHAhVIGY4KHQhZA-s&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fjamierumbelow%2Fcodeigniter-base-model&ei=bfbGVcmZO8iyuASIso3YDg&usg=AFQjCNGREFhLtLFxiZLwO3NWSkeQFPQdNA&sig2=hUi6c8tL5oxkG3zkgFs5VQ&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E),and if you want to make your design responsive use Bootstrap.

Comment: can you tell me for more detail please?
which code in my source code must be edit,
so i can save it into Database SQL, thx

Comment: @karisma can you tell me what error are you getting right now? that can help me debug.. because your form does not matter saving the data as your form is only the front end you just need to grab the values you get in POST